# Sparse Signal fitting in MATLAB, for a sinusoidal function with more than 8 terms?

Tags: matlab, sparsity

I'm trying to fit some data belong to a sum of sines function (Fourier sparse) in MATLAB, however, the number of terms of sine function in MATLAB is limited,i.e. to $1 \leq n \leq 8$. However, I want more terms in my fit functions, i.e. over $50$ terms. By the way I do not intent to recover the signal using Compressive-sensing sparse recovery methods or Fourier based curve fitting and my goal is not signal estimation.

- Is there anyway to make MATLAB to fit my data to a sum of sine function with over 8 sinusoidal terms?
- Why there is such constraint in MATLAB (is it technically or arbitrary)? - Is there any toolbox to fit sinusoidal function (especially something that is capable of supporting wieghted data)?

  ```
  f = fit(X,Y, 'sin10')
  Error using fittype>iCreateFromLibrary (line 412)
  Library function sin10 not found.
  ```

It is o.k up to `sin8` or `sin9` parameters.

I appreciate any answer.

Comment: Does each additional term have an increase infrequency proportional to the fundamental frequency (such that you are basically finding the Fourier series)? Because then each sine fit should be independent of each other, because these sine functions are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: No, actually the frequencies are randomly chosen. I can't employ fourier, because of leakage.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more why you cannot use the Fourier Transform to analyse a function into a sum of sinusoids, **especially** when the result might be sparse? What sort of discriminating capability are you going for? What is the shortest distance (in Hz) you expect two frequencies to end up with? Also, can you say a little bit more about the actual problem you are dealing with?

Comment: @A_A , first, the problem with FFT is leakage (to avoid leakage I must know exactly the frequencies to make window length is the most appropriate) , other than leakage, I have a big problem. Some points in my samples have greater priority than other (like 20% of data are more accurate measurements of the signal). Through curve fitting I can easily wight these important data more. – Mimsaad 38 mins ago

Comment: Are you after their parameters or fitting in order to have higher sampling resolution of the data?

Comment: @Royi I was but I do not remember due to some issue I abandoned it

Comment: @MimSaad, Which one of the 2 options?

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB has a curve-fitting toolbox where you pass a function of your choice to the fit function. Hence, the number of terms is totally up to you in this case.

If you do not have a curve-fitting toolbox, you could try to find a free one or write a fit function by yourself (e.g. with fminsearch). However, this is not the fastest algorithm and also you would have to calculate the fitting errors by yourself.

**Reply to your comment**

```
FitOptions = fitoptions('Method','NonlinearLeastSquares', 'Algorithm', 'Trust-Region', 'MaxIter');
FitType = fittype('a*sin(1*f) + b*sin(2*f) + c*sin(3*f) + d*sin(4*f) + e*sin(5*f) + g*sin(6*f) + h*sin(7*f) + k*sin(8*f) + l*sin(9*f) + m*sin(10*f) + n*sin(11*f)', 'independent', 'f');
[FittedModel, GOF] = fit(freq, data, FitType)
```

will certainly fit the sum of sines with the prefactors. And, of course, scaling parameters in the individual sine's arguments. However, since I do not have MATLAB available here, I cannot verify this. But from my experience, `fit()` has no such restriction. The restriction you experience comes most likely from the limitations of an internal function library that you are using (see the "sin10" string in your example - this is a call to an built-in, predefined function.)

Comment: Thanks, however I am aware of that toolbox, as I said it does not support fitting sum of sines with more than 8 term.

Comment: See the updated answer, please. You are not using the `fit()` function with its full flexibility, I assume.

Comment: Honestly, I was just testing this method,and in first shop it did not bring the results I desire (however, the same test data when I use 'sin8' parameters give good results). I think this method is right and I only must adjust Initiation values of the algorithm properly. I''ll check it and let you know.

Comment: "(see the "sin10" string in your example - this is a call to an built-in, predefined function.) " And I wonder why they restrict to only 8 sinusoidal terms? Is the algorithm the culprit?

Comment: No, it is not the algorithm. It is the fact that you cannot provide an infinite number of built-in functions. At a certain level of detail or complexity, you have to type in your own function. There is no sense in trying to provide functions for each use case.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Honestly, I was in mistake in case of both lsqcurvefit and fit instructions. I recently realized (from Matlab help) that Sum of Sine fitting is too sensitive to Starting Points (or initial values). On the other hand, when you choose "Custom Function" fitting mode, Matlab generates random values for starting point, however, when you choose predefined function fitting (like 'sin1','sin2',...) , initial values are generated based on some heuristic method which is the reason that predefined functions fit so well! (you can find the heuristic function called 'startpt.m' in Matlab root functions.

Comment: Of course you can issue the starting points from an self-written heuristic to the fit function structure. Along with upper and lower boundaries, if you choose so.

Comment: @Mimsaad : What is wrong with this answer? It seems correct. I was going to post [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html) as a comment on your question, but M529 seems to have used it and explained how to get what you need. If you've found an answer using `lsqcurvefit`, please post it here as an answer.

Comment: @Peter K. , you right I'v found the answer, but unfortunately the question is on hold! As I have mentioned in one my comments, neither 'fit' instruction was the culprit, nor the 'lsqcurvefit' instruction was the solution, both in fact do the same thing. The solution was selection of proper starting points for the fitting algorithm. Unfortunately fitting of sum of sines to the data is too sensitive to initial points, when you use matlab predefined function,it selects best starting points but when you use custom function fitting, the starting points are chosen randomly and hence coverage occurs

Comment: @Mimsaad  I reopened the question when I posted my comment above. Try refreshing your browser.